# function gives me TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a javascript function inside reactjs.

I import like this:

```
import { ImageTools } from './resize_javascript';
```

and I use like this:

```
upload = (image) => {
    ImageTools.resize(image, {
        width: 320, // maximum width
        height: 240 // maximum height
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
        document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(blob);
```

image is ok, has the image properts. I think ImageTools is not import correctly or something because it works in my html/js code but when import to react it gives me `TypeError: Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined` after select an image.

any ideas what is wrong?

thanks!

---

```
the full js if needed:

'use strict';

if (typeof exports === "undefined") {
    var exports = {};
}

if (typeof module === "undefined") {
   var module = {};
}

Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', {
    value: true
});

var _createClass = (function () { function defineProperties(target, props) { for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) { var descriptor = props[i]; descriptor.enumerable = descriptor.enumerable || false; descriptor.configurable = true; if ('value' in descriptor) descriptor.writable = true; Object.defineProperty(target, descriptor.key, descriptor); } } return function (Constructor, protoProps, staticProps) { if (protoProps) defineProperties(Constructor.prototype, protoProps); if (staticProps) defineProperties(Constructor, staticProps); return Constructor; }; })();

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError('Cannot call a class as a function'); } }

var hasBlobConstructor = typeof Blob !== 'undefined' && (function () {
    try {
        return Boolean(new Blob());
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
})();

var hasArrayBufferViewSupport = hasBlobConstructor && typeof Uint8Array !== 'undefined' && (function () {
    try {
        return new Blob([new Uint8Array(100)]).size === 100;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
})();

var hasToBlobSupport = typeof HTMLCanvasElement !== "undefined" ? HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toBlob : false;

var hasBlobSupport = hasToBlobSupport || typeof Uint8Array !== 'undefined' && typeof ArrayBuffer !== 'undefined' && typeof atob !== 'undefined';

var hasReaderSupport = typeof FileReader !== 'undefined' || typeof URL !== 'undefined';

var ImageTools = (function () {
    function ImageTools() {
        _classCallCheck(this, ImageTools);
    }

    _createClass(ImageTools, null, [{
        key: 'resize',
        value: function resize(file, maxDimensions, callback) {
            if (typeof maxDimensions === 'function') {
                callback = maxDimensions;
                maxDimensions = {
                    width: 640,
                    height: 480
                };
            }

            var maxWidth = maxDimensions.width;
            var maxHeight = maxDimensions.height;

            if (!ImageTools.isSupported() || !file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
                callback(file, false);
                return false;
            }

            if (file.type.match(/image\/gif/)) {
                // Not attempting, could be an animated gif
                callback(file, false);
                // TODO: use https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy to convert gif to webm
                return false;
            }

            var image = document.createElement('img');

            image.onload = function (imgEvt) {
                var width = image.width;
                var height = image.height;
                var isTooLarge = false;

                if (width > height && width > maxDimensions.width) {
                    // width is the largest dimension, and it's too big.
                    height *= maxDimensions.width / width;
                    width = maxDimensions.width;
                    isTooLarge = true;
                } else if (height > maxDimensions.height) {
                    // either width wasn't over-size or height is the largest dimension
                    // and the height is over-size
                    width *= maxDimensions.height / height;
                    height = maxDimensions.height;
                    isTooLarge = true;
                }

                if (!isTooLarge) {
                    // early exit; no need to resize
                    callback(file, false);
                    return;
                }

                var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                canvas.width = width;
                canvas.height = height;

                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

                if (hasToBlobSupport) {
                    canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {
                        callback(blob, true);
                    }, file.type);
                } else {
                    var blob = ImageTools._toBlob(canvas, file.type);
                    callback(blob, true);
                }
            };
            ImageTools._loadImage(image, file);

            return true;
        }
    }, {
        key: '_toBlob',
        value: function _toBlob(canvas, type) {
            var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL(type);
            var dataURIParts = dataURI.split(',');
            var byteString = undefined;
            if (dataURIParts[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0) {
                // Convert base64 to raw binary data held in a string:
                byteString = atob(dataURIParts[1]);
            } else {
                // Convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data:
                byteString = decodeURIComponent(dataURIParts[1]);
            }
            var arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
            var intArray = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);

            for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i += 1) {
                intArray[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var mimeString = dataURIParts[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0];
            var blob = null;

            if (hasBlobConstructor) {
                blob = new Blob([hasArrayBufferViewSupport ? intArray : arrayBuffer], { type: mimeString });
            } else {
                let bb = new Blob()
                bb.append(arrayBuffer);
                blob = bb.getBlob(mimeString);
            }

            return blob;
        }
    }, {
        key: '_loadImage',
        value: function _loadImage(image, file, callback) {
            if (typeof URL === 'undefined') {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (evt) {
                    image.src = evt.target.result;
                    if (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                if (callback) {
                    callback();
                }
            }
        }
    }, {
        key: 'isSupported',
        value: function isSupported() {
            return typeof HTMLCanvasElement !== 'undefined' && hasBlobSupport && hasReaderSupport;
        }
    }]);

    return ImageTools;
})();

exports['default'] = ImageTools;
module.exports = exports['default'];
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is at your import statement.

While you are exporting `ImageTools` as default, you should import it like:

`import ImageTools from './resize_javascript';`

Answer (score 1):

The right code is:

```
import ImageTools from './resize_javascript'; // <-- import as default

upload = (image) => {
    ImageTools.resize(image, {
        width: 320, // maximum width
        height: 240 // maximum height
    }, function(blob, didItResize) {
        document.getElementById('preview').src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

      const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${image.name}`).put(blob);

/*...*/
```